# Get string and wrap it in <a>

Tags: jquery, regex, string, hyperlink

I have some HTML that is dynamically generated, so I cannot edit the HTML. The HTML looks like (1). I want it to look like (2). So basically, the string at the end of the `li`'s should be cut and pasted into an `<a>` that is then wrapped around the other text. Also the trailing `-` should get removed then.

**HTML** (1)

```
<ul>
  <li>Jovanotti – L'ombelico Del Mondo - http://youtu.be/mMNPUw2bUhM</li>
  <li>The Police – Roxanne - http://youtu.be/3T1c7GkzRQQ</li>
</ul>
```

What it should look like (2)

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://youtu.be/mMNPUw2bUhM" title="">Jovanotti – L'ombelico Del Mondo</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://youtu.be/3T1c7GkzRQQ" title="">The Police – Roxanne</a></li>
</ul>
```

It is a different question than the ones that are already asked on SO. I do not know the contents of the "url", only that it always starts with `http://youtu.be`.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7EhhS/) to play with.

Comment: How are you getting the HTML, and why can't you edit it?

Comment: Could you be more specific and explain your question ? Jsfiddle link to your code if possible.

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly I edited the question thoroughly.

Comment: @MattBusche As you can see in my edit, it is **not** a duplicate, though it does look a bit the same.

Comment: @Dai Because it is added dynamically.

Comment: @BramVanroy Based on your initial criteria, which was one line, it was a duplicate.

Comment: @MattBusche I understand that, but now it is not anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the elements, use `.split` to break up the string by ' - ' then pop off the last element (the url) and `.join` the rest of the string back together with ' - ' between the elements.

```
$('ul li').each(function () {
    var li = $(this),
        parts = li.text().split(' - ');
    li.html('<a href="' + parts.pop() + '">' + parts.join(' - ') + '</a>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rustyjeans/89whD/

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a combination of [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner) and [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each):

```
$('ul li').wrapInner('<a>').find('a').each(function(i,el) {
    var arrCont = $(el).text().split(/\s*-\s*http/),
        strText = arrCont[0],
        strUrl = "http"+arrCont[1];
    $(el).attr('href',strUrl).attr('title','').text(strText);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Ax8QU/